# Spring & JSP: how to evaluate expression in a variable?

Tags: spring, jsp, properties

What I need to do:

```
<compress:js enabled="<spring:eval expression="@propertyConfigurer.getProperty('code.compress')"/>" jsCompressor="closure">
...
</compress:js>
```

code.compress is set to true in the .properties and available. The problem is JSP page is rendering with the following error:

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/template/default/centerCol.jsp (line: 23, column: 47) Unterminated <compress:js tag

So, where is my mistake?

Thank you.

P.S. Spring 4.2

Answer (score 3):

Solution is pretty simple:

```
<c:set var="compress">
    <spring:eval expression="@propertyConfigurer.getProperty('code.compress')"/>
</c:set>
<compress:js enabled="${compress}" jsCompressor="closure">
...
</compress:js>
```

Comment: How would this fix the reported problem of unterminated tag? You just moved the expression around.

Comment: I guess, the problem was that spring tried to evaluate an expression, but htmlcompressor is not working with such substitution.

Comment: Ah, OK, fair enough - although it would be useful to include this explanation directly in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the error shows that you need to close the compress tag:

```
<c:set var="compress">
    <spring:eval expression="@propertyConfigurer.getProperty('code.compress')"/>
</c:set>
<compress:js enabled="${compress}" jsCompressor="closure"/>
```

There's a closing tag after "closure".

Comment: actually, it was an excerpt from the code - I have </compress:js> below. I've added it to the my answer.